# When to use NoSQL vs SQL for BI data

Tags: sql, database, business-intelligence, nosql

I'm using data stored within a SQL database (mariadDB) to store information about "widgets" and "products".

Widgets have metadata associated with them and some relational data associated.  Like build team, builders, and an image.  Builders can be on any number of teams and any team can build any widget.  Currently this data is normalized into separate tables and mapping mapping/associative tables.

Products also have metadata; description, what it was used for, when it was delivered, etc.

The products and widgets tables seem to be a good fit for a NoSQL solution.  Perhaps having to de-normalize builders and build teams.

Where the data does not seem to be a good fit for NoSQL is the relationship between products and widgets.  Widgets can be associated/mapped to 0 or more products. Each widget mapped to a product provides a capability to that product (Widget A may provide a web service, Widget B may provide locomotion, etc.).

Every once in a while the suite of products changes and the widgets are then re-mapped to the new set of products.  The data is being used with Business Intelligence (BI) software (Jaspersoft Studio) to generate reports.

The data is not large. It is for our internal team use and to generate reports for other teams as they request them.  So I'm not worried about ACID compliance or write locks, vertical or horizontal scaling, 24x7 availability, and those sorts of thing. My primary concern is flexibility as the data changes (meta data captured about the widgets and the set of products the widgets are applied to).

1. Based on my research NoSQL should be avoided if your data is at all relational.  These Articles were rather old and I'm wondering if this is still the case?
2. When the suite of products changes it is painful to re-map the widgets to the new suite.  Notionally, it seems that NoSQL solution could help ease that pain.  But I'm not sure how.

Answer (score 2):

SQL is better with set operations and relations, it will also be faster in filtering the sets you are working with. 
NoSQL has greater flexibility of functions and can do some single row operations faster.

I would recommend having two environments if you need to use NoSQL, the SQL for housing all the data and NoSQL to do calculations for you. To feed the data into NoSQL best practice would be to create table valued functions or views.